# How do I create a gradient button on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, gradient

How can I create a button that looks like the one found in the screenshot below on an iPhone with the 3.0 SDK?  It's a button that shows when connecting to a host iTunes library from the iTunes remote.

Is it a case of writing a custom control or is this a stock style?

[iTunes Remote Button http://grab.by/grabs/3bbb59936d86da2c95c7afa4c9c78677.png](http://grab.by/grabs/3bbb59936d86da2c95c7afa4c9c78677.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either (1) subclass UIButton and draw the gradient yourself in drawRect, or (2) use stock UIButton with images that have the look you want, or (3) use stock UIButton but add a CALayer that contains a gradient.

The rounded corners, colors and border are all possible with the stock UIButton.

Comment: Great, looks like I can have a go with the custom gradient drawing option first then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to create images for default, highlighted, disabled states and create a custom button with all these images.